# pyrcc5: No such file or directory

Tags: python-3.7, labelimg

I want to install labelImg for mac OS in python 3.7. here is the repo: https://github.com/tzutalin/labelImg

I have installed previous modules via 'pip3 install pyqt5 lxml' successfully. Cloned the repo, entered the folder 'labelImg', but only 'make qt5py3' does not work..

but when I execute 'make qt5py3', i get the error

```
pyrcc5 -o libs/resources.py resources.qrc
make: pyrcc5: No such file or directory
make: *** [qt5py3] Error 1
```

What can I do here? What might have caused the issue?

Comment: I have the same issue

Comment: I have created an issue for this on the github repo  https://github.com/tzutalin/labelImg/issues/512

Answer (score 0):

-find 'pyrcc5' under python bin, and copy 'path'

-under labelImg find 'Makefile' and edit

-change line
`qt5py3: pyrcc5` to `qt5py3: 'copied path'/pyrcc5`
and save

-and

```
make qt5py3
python labelImg.py
```

should works.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues as the OP, but with Python 3.6.11. In addition, I got ModuleNotFoundErrors for pyqt5 and libxml2, even though brew confirmed they were both installed. Also, I was trying to install in a virtual environment set up using pyenv.

What finally worked for me was:

```
   1) use global env, not virtual
   2) use pip (not pip3) to install pyqt5 and lxml
   3) change the makefile as @zippo suggested
```

After I did  that, I was able to get labelImg to start by running:

```
python labelImg.py
```